# Moved Root to new SSD, but df shows old root after boot

Tags: partitioning, ssd, root, boot-partition

I moved my root (excluding home) to a new SSD partition and when I boot I have the option to use it. It seems clear that I am now on this new system, because my system is faster, but the df command shows that / (root) is on the old partition.

gparted shows that both the old and the new are / (root)

What is going on? To be clear the goal is to have sda1 as the root.

Under is the output of lsblk for the relevant devices:

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT    LABEL      SIZE FSTYPE UUID
fd0                               4K        
sda                           119.2G        
├─sda1                         24.4G ext4   7ade9c23-ed72-4ccc-86e5-b7cb24b97443
└─sda2                            2M        
sdb                           931.5G        
├─sdb1 /home                  906.6G ext4   813bd658-c034-4a51-a6bb-c91190aa3f43
├─sdb4 /                       20.3G ext4   ff5e5435-bfe8-465f-b94a-2857b97238ea
└─sdb5 [SWAP]                   4.6G swap   d10c3755-2b76-4955-8267-da95996b7c30
sdc                           149.1G        
└─sdc1 /media/backup          149.1G ext4   73e5eb4d-936e-487c-9bb9-df96fea192cf
sdf                           297.4G        
└─sdf1               JESSE HD 297.4G exfat  555E-4A38
sr0                             668M        
Model: ATA ADATA SU800 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 2      1049kB  3146kB  2097kB                     bios_grub
 1      3146kB  26.2GB  26.2GB  ext4               boot, esp

Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 4      1049kB  21.7GB  21.7GB  primary   ext4
 1      21.7GB  995GB   973GB   primary   ext4
 2      995GB   1000GB  4975MB  extended
 5      995GB   1000GB  4974MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Will you edit your question and append the output of: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it myself. The issue was that I followed two guides for my setup and didn't use the right grub installation. Using this guide it worked when I made sure to follow step 7 for grub installation: https://frankfzw.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/migrate-ubuntu-14-04-from-hdd-to-ssd/

Make sure to look at the update in the comments for this step!!

You can exit the chroot with ctl-d for those who don't commonly use them.

Thanks..